# iPhone - Using front or rear camera using AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureDevice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, camera, avcapturesession

Which is the right way to use the front or the rear camera using AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureDevice?

I can see that the `position` attribute of the AVCapturedevice is read-only, and I don't see any other way to tell which device we want to use, as it can be done with the UIImagePicker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `[AVCaptureDevice devices]` to enumerate the devices and look at the `position` property to distinguish the front and rear (where they exist).

There's some example code in [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/objc/src/ZXing/ZXCapture.mm). (For iOS, `ZXCaptureDevice` is `AVCaptureDevice` in `ZXCapture`).